# Bootstrap datetime picker not working for directives in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

I am using Bootstrap Datetime picker where the data is taken from json file, converting into proper date format and then displaying it in calender. I have To date and From date.

```
scope.onHide = function(e) {              
  var frmDateVal = $j("#fromdatetimepicker").val();
  var toDateVal = $j("#todatetimepicker").val();
  scope.fromDate = scope.dateTimetoUTCMilliseconds(frmDateVal);
  scope.toDate = scope.dateTimetoUTCMilliseconds(toDateVal);
  scope.plotDataSeries();
  scope.$digest();
};


$("#fromdatetimepicker").on("dp.change", function (e) {
  $('#todatetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
});
```

What is the solution for replacement of `$("#element")` in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this post to avoid using jQuery in angularJS the wrong way : ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Also, there is a library existing in AngularJS that can help you using Bootstrap components : this is UI Bootstrap.

You can find the datepicker documentation for this library here :
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

I think it would be the easier way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i am looking for solution like datetime picker in the same event click. So if you could help me with that it would be helpful. Apart from that i am using link function.